# Cannot get api data from Twilio using Guzzle 6.x

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, twilio, guzzle

I am trying to retrieve a list of faxes I have sent.  According to the documentation at Twilio, I can get the list at https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes (I of course had to supply my authtoken and sid).  I am now trying to replicate the same thing using Guzzle 6.x.  Here is my code (I am using codeigniter 3.x ):

```
// fax history
function fax_history(){

    // get the account sid                    
     $mh_twilio_fax_account_sid  = $this->config->item('mh_twilio_fax_account_sid');

    // get the auth token for the account
     $mh_twilio_auth_token       = $this->config->item('mh_twilio_auth_token');

    // create a new guzzle client
    $guzzleResource = new guzzleClient();

    // guzzle up the data
    $res = $guzzleResource->request('GET', 'https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes', [
        'auth' => [$mh_twilio_fax_account_sid, $mh_twilio_auth_token]
    ]);

    // test to see if the right data is returned
    $this->data['status_code']   = $res->getStatusCode();
    $this->data['content_type']  = $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
    $this->data['faxes']        = $res->getBody();

    // Set the titles
    $this->data['mh_admin_title']      = $this->data['mh_title_admin'] .' | Fax List - '.$this->module_view_name;

    // nominate the view file
    $this->data['mh_admin_view_file']   = $this->module_system_name .'/admin/'.$this->module_system_name.'-admin-fax-history';

    // load up the view
    $this->load->view($this->mh_template, $this->data);
}
```

After the code is run, I see the following in the view file for  $this->data['status_code'], $this->data['content_type']  and  $this->data['faxes'] :

$this->data['status_code'] says 200
$this->data['content_type'] says application/json
$this->data['faxes'] does not give me the list of faxes I can see at https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes.  Instead, it shows:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object (
 [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #47
 [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
 [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
 [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
 [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
 [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
 [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

How am I able to obtain the fax info which should looking something like this:

```
"meta": {"page": 0, "page_size": 50, "first_page_url": 
"https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes?PageSize=50&Page=0", "previous_page_url": 
null, "url": "https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes?PageSize=50&Page=0", 
"next_page_url": null, "key": "faxes"}, "faxes": [{"media_sid": 
"*snip*", "status": "delivered", "direction": "outbound", "from": 
"+81removed", "date_updated": "2019-01-02T08:16:43Z", "price": "-21.6", 
"account_sid": "*snip*", "to": "+81removed", "date_created": "2019-01- 
02T08:13:15Z", "url": 
"https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes/FXe588329bf71f3f411da742d84838a25a", "sid": 
"*snip*", "duration": 193, "num_pages": 1, "quality": "fine", "price_unit": 
"JPY", "api_version": "v1", "media_url": 
"https://media.twiliocdn.com/fax/*snip*/*snip?x-amz-security-   etc etc
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have cURL installed on the server?

Comment: I am not using cUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guzzle 6 implements psr7.  To access the contents the correct way is:

```
$this->data['faxes'] = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```